# What does 'make drones' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, usage

Who can tell me the meaning of 'make drones' in the following?

> Here is the context: The U.S. and other countries have seen a flurry of apps that are inspired by Meitu, the Chinese app that pretties up selfie photos. American startups are copying China's fleets of on-demand bicycle rentals for getting around crowded cities. Apple and Facebook are trying to remold their messaging apps in the image of China's ubiquitous WeChat. Before there was Tinder for hookups, there was similar dating app Momo in China. Every company that **makes drones** is following the lead of China's SZ DJI Technology.

Is it used as a metaphor? If so, what is compared to what?

Comment: [So, you found a sentence or phrase… (Why you should cite your source)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/)

Answer (score 1):

The verb *make* means *produce, manufacture*.
[Bloomberg says](https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapid=270064016) of SZ DJI Technology:

> SZ DJI Technology Co., Ltd. develops and markets unmanned aerial systems. It offers flying platforms, aerial gimbals, flight controllers, and propulsion systems.

From [their site](http://www.dji.com/products/drones#consumer-nav), the kinds of drones they make are these
[image]